# NSMutableString: Need to insert no value instead of (null)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablestring

I am passing the value of string to a web service. if the string has some value then it is ok.

but if does not contain any value which is null, it prints (null).

for eg:

```
NSMutableString *str1 = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@""];
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"str1 has %@ value", str1];

NSLog(@"%@", string);
```

Should print : str1 has    value

instead it prints: str1 has (null) value

Comment: It prints "str1 has  value" for me, like you'd expect. Are you sure the problem isn't elsewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the expression `str1 ?: @""` to use the string, or an empty string if it's nil.